# Stored Procedures: Addition of two numbers by passing them as parameters

Tags: parameters, addition

I am currently learning stored procedures, and have been trying to do the simple exercise of adding two numbers by passing them to my sp. 
The problem I'm facing is with data type conversions and loss of data.
I'm defining my procedure as follows:

```
create proc addn(@a float, @b float)
as
begin
declare @sum varchar
set @sum=cast((@a+@b) as varchar)
print 'the sum of '+cast(@a as varchar)+' and '+cast(@b as varchar)+' is ' cast((@a+@b) as varchar)
print @sum
end
```

The procedure is being called as follows:

```
declare @a1 float, @b1 float
set @a1=41
set @b1=6.2
exec addn @a1,@b1
```

The result I'm getting is:

```
the sum of 41 and 6.2 is 47.2
4
```

Now I can't understand why I'm getting only a 4 in @sum. It is storing only the first digit of the result of any addition that is performed. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is in declaring parameter `@sum`. In your case data type of variable `@sum` is only varchar, and SQL will assume that it is only one character, so you must put some int value in brackets, like VARCHAR(4) or something else.

```
create proc addn(@a float, @b float)
as
begin
declare @sum varchar(4)
set @sum=cast((@a+@b) as VARCHAR)
print 'the sum of '+cast(@a as varchar) + ' and ' + cast(@b as varchar) + ' is ' + cast((@a+@b) as VARCHAR)
print @sum
END
```

Comment: Thank you!
That answers my question very well.